# Java regex replace string with special characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace `<keyword>` with a string.

```
String result = "<keyword>".replace(Pattern.quote("<keyword>"), "text");
```

Expected result: `text`

Got result: `<keyword>`

Any ideas?

Comment: `String result = "<keyword>".replace("<keyword>", "text");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `String.replace` doesn't use regex parameters you can just use

```
String result = "<keyword>".replace("<keyword>", "text");
```

Comment: for some reason i thought `replace` expected regex

Comment: replaceAll expects regex , replace expects normal string

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use `replaceAll` which uses a regex instead of `replace` that doesn't.

```
String result = "<keyword>".replaceAll("<keyword>", "text");
```

If you check the **[replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))** javadocs you will find:

[image]